# Stop accessing function direct or URL call

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make function which is insert data to database after submitting.
But when I try to access the insert function, it occurs db error. How can I stop this function from direct/URL call access.

Comment: What is the error? and the relevant code?

Comment: You can add this to your file at start.  <?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller function you can use

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
//Your code goes here
}
```

this if to off direct access from GET URL request.

**OR**

You can declare your function as `private` which will be only accessible inside of that **Controller** class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a controller method restricted by declaring it private.

As in, `private function _mymethod() {`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#private-methods